# Fonts too bold in imageMagick (php)

Tags: php, fonts, imagemagick, gd, truetype

I'm moving code from PHP GD to ImageMagick

Sample GD code :

```
$base_image=imagecreatetruecolor ( 350, 350 );

$white  = imagecolorallocatealpha($base_image, 255, 255, 255, 100);
imagefill($base_image , 0, 0, $white);

imagealphablending($base_image, true);
imagesavealpha($base_image, true);


$black = imagecolorallocatealpha ($base_image, 0,0,0, 1);

imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  30, $black, './arial.ttf', "Hello World!"); 
imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  60, $black, './arib____.ttf', "Hello World!");
imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  90, $black, './verdana.ttf', "Hello World!");
imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  120, $black, './trebuc.ttf', "Hello World!");
imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  150, $black, './georgia.ttf', "Hello World!");


header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($base_image);
```

Sample ImageMAgic Code:

```
$canvas = new Imagick();

$canvas->newImage(350, 350, "white");

$draw = new ImagickDraw();


$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$draw->setStrokeWidth ( 2); 

$draw->setFontSize(13*96/72);


$draw->setFont('./arial.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, 30, "Hello World!");
$draw->setFont('./arib____.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, 60, "Hello World!");
$draw->setFont('./verdana.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, 90, "Hello World!");
$draw->setFont('./trebuc.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, 120, "Hello World!");
$draw->setFont('./georgia.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, 150, "Hello World!");


$canvas->drawImage($draw);
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
```

The result in ImageMagic is much bolder font.
[image: GD]
[image: Imagick]

Note that they both use the same ttf font files.
I played with all possible settings in imageMagic including setFontStyle setStrokeOpacity, setStrokeWidth, setStrokeAntialias, setTextAntialias, setStrokeColor, setFillColor in imageMagic and I cant make it look like the GD version.

How can I avoid the over baldness?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use almost-white (#FFFFFE) instead of exactly white?  That would indicate a problem with the colorspace that existed in some old versions of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

most likely setStrokeWidth() results in the extra bold. It did for me.